# ASP.NET - Change label color and conc with string

Tags: c#, asp.net, colors, label

I create a label and set his TEXT color to red. I use **ForeColor** property but with him not working :(

**This is my UI:**

[image]

**This is my label code:**

```
        Label reqF = new Label();
        reqF.Text = "*";
        reqF.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        reqF.CssClass = "formvalidation";
        reqF.Font.Size = 15; // 15px
```

**This is my string code:**

```
        TableHeaderCell header1 = new TableHeaderCell();
        header1.Text = "Destination" + reqF.Text;  <----------- My label
        tRow0.Cells.Add(header1);
```

Comment: Which control are we actually looking at in the output?  If it's the `TableHeaderCell`, where do you modify *its* color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
header1.Text = "Destination" + reqF.Text;
```

you add only the text (*) to the destination, not the full div with the style on.

The easiest (and faster) way is to direct add the style online as:

```
header1.Text = "Destination <span style=\"color=red\">*</span>" ;
```

Comment: @Gohyu try this `header1.Text = "Destination" + "<span style='color=red'>*</span>"`

Answer (score 1):

You are only using text of the control, not the whole control with styling. Your code should actually look something like that:

```
TableHeaderCell header1 = new TableHeaderCell();
LiteralControl literal = new LiteralControl();
literal.Text = "Destination";
header1.Controls.Add(literal);
header1.Controls.Add(reqF);
tRow0.Cells.Add(header1);
```

Note that here `Literal` control is used to insert the `Description` string, and then the whole Label with the `*` is being inserted.